# What programming language and libraries could I use to automate this Blender to Unreal Engine pipeline?

Tags: automation, ui-automation, blender, unreal-engine4

> What programming language and libraries could I use to automate a Blender to Unreal Engine pipeline?

I want to automate the following steps (on Windows/Linux)

- Open Blender from specified path by user input
- Open a specified `.blend` file
- execute a Blender script which manipulates the `.blend` file
- if execution was successful, proceed with exporting the current `.blend` file as `.fbx` to a specified path by user input, otherwise just throw an error
- open UE4
- create a new third-person game project under specified path by user input
- open the newly created project
- import the `.fbx` file

What programming language and libraries/package could I use to automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PYTHON !
python is the language blender understands internally
within python you got import sys to do file system things and execute run other apps
to control the non python apps checkout https://bigl.es/tuesday-tooling-simulate-keyboard-input-with-python/